# Minimum Number of states for a Turing Machine

Tags: computer-science, turing-machines

I am looking for a Turing Machine $M$ with $k$ states such that there is no other Turing Machine $M$' with fewer than $k$ states that recognizes the same language as $M$ (i.e., $L(M) = L(M')$). We suppose the tape alphabet is $\Gamma=\{0,1,b\}$ for all $TM$, hence we cannot use new symbols to represent states. Also, there's only one accepting and rejecting state and the result is written on the tape.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Turing_machine#Smallest_machines

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to mention that the alphabet of the machines we consider must be binary, so we cannot add symbols to the tape alphabet.

Comment: Given the restriction on the set of tape symbols, can you clarify how the input is provided to the machine? Using the terminology from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine#Formal_definition), do you have $\Gamma=\{0,1,b\}$? How is the accept/reject result represented?

Comment: Yes, we have $\Gamma=\{0,1,b\}$, there's an accepting and rejecting state and the result of the calculation is written on the tape.

Comment: Why I was posting the Wikipedia article was just to mention that you can build a universal Turing machine with only a few states.  So, as far as I understand, your approach would help to classify simple languages, which need fewer states than a universal Turing machine, but as soon as you can simulate a uiversal Turing machine, your score stops increasing.